# $f(0)= f'(0) = f'(1) = 0, f(1) = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $A$ be the set of three times continuously differentiable functions from $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ following the conditions in the title. What is the value of : 
$$ \sup_{f\in A} \inf f'''(x)$$

It is rather well known that $||f''||_{\infty} \ge 4$, but I have no idea how to find the value I'm trying to calculate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $p(x) = 3x^2 - 2x^3$ and $g(x) = f(x) - p(x)$. Then
$$
 g(0) = g'(0) = g'(1) = g(1) = 0
$$
and repeated application of Rolle's theorem shows that for some $a \in (0,1)$
$$
 0 = g'''(a) = f'''(a) -  p'''(a) = f'''(a) + 12
$$
so that
$$
 \inf_{x \in [0,1]} f'''(x) \le f'''(a) = -12 \, .
$$
Equality holds for $f = p$, therefore
$$
 \sup_{f \in A }\inf_{x \in [0,1]} f'''(x) = -12 \,.
$$

Comment: Nice and short solution! Thanks